# CSS Parallax works in Chrome, but not Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, parallax, css-transforms

As far as I'm aware, as documented by Keith Clark's blog post on pure CSS parallax [here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/), CSS parallax should work in all major browsers except IE, since Microsoft has not as of yet implemented support for `transform-style:preserve-3d`.

Yet, my own basic implementation of this effect, demonstrated here in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uurwetbk/1/), works in Chrome 39, but does not Firefox 34. The latter does not seem to even be applying the

```
.back {
    transform:translateZ(-2px);
}
```

style. What is the reason for this? Is there any fix? I've attempted to disable and enable various properties on each element to no success. Yet, I'm at a loss to explain how Keith Clark's implementation [here](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/demo3/) works, yet mine does not.

Comment: Does it work with vendor prefixes?

Comment: @Seer, no, and CanIUse reports that the moz vendor prefix has not been necessary for 3D transformations for some time now.

Comment: I copied all of his code into this: http://codepen.io/hwg/pen/jErjxV, you might want to compare them and see what you are missing (except the superfluous styling)

Answer (score 3):

there are a couple of problems in the HTML that are preventing Firefox from working. The first is that `.container` with `overflow:hidden` is a direct parent of your parallax items. Your body tag (which already has the specific parallax overflow settings `overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;`) needs to be the direct parent of your parallax-group.

Second, your non-parallax items (the lorem ipsum paragraphs) also need `position: relative;` and a z-index so you can control the layering. I tried it in FF on your JSFiddle page and it works. I was trying to solve the same problem myself because the non-direct wrapper causes different problems in Chrome.